# Find and replace character from the string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table in that one column of varchar type I want to replace all data which have **'?'** with **'-'** for **every row**.

For example I have following data

```
Substance Abuse Facility ? Outpatient
Substance Abuse Facility ? Inpatient
```

and result should be

```
Substance Abuse Facility - Outpatient
Substance Abuse Facility – Inpatient
```

Can someone help me to form this query, only **'?'** should be replace with **'-'**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET mycolumn = REPLACE ( mycolumn , '?' , '-' )
```